# Creating a button to add multiple classes to multiple buttons and remove them when clicking on reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 different buttons each have a common class and a unique class.

```
<button type="button" class="topic btn1" data-target="desc1">Safety</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn2" data-target="desc2">Environment</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn3" data-target="desc3">Climate change</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn4" data-target="desc4">Sustainability</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn5" data-target="desc5">Business strategy</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn6" data-target="desc6">Performance data</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn7" data-target="desc7">Working for Shell</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn8" data-target="desc8">Working together</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn9" data-target="desc9">Social performance</button>
<button type="button" class="topic btn10" data-target="desc10">Human rights</button>
```

A function is applied on that which will add one extra unique class to each button.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
  $( ".btn" + i ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn" + i );
  });
}
```

Now i want to create two buttons:-

1. Show All: When some one click on this, third unique class `act-btn1` to `act-btn10` will be added in the same order.
2. Reset: When someone click on that reset button, only the extra added class will be removed, rest will be same.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want it to work in this way? I ask as incremental id and class attributes are generally an anti-pattern to be avoided as they make the logic far more complex and difficult to maintain than it needs to be. For example in this case you could achieve what you require with common classes and identifying each element by its index within the parent container.

Comment: There is a reason for using multiple classes instated of id's, as i am creating a design in which these buttons will show in mobile devices and another design will show in desktop devices.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are encountering to achieve your requirements.  You already have a function that toggles the class - are you looking for `.addClass` and `.removeClass`?  Are you looking for how to add an event handler?  Rather than only describe what you want - what's the specific problem that stopping you getting there?

Comment: "*show in mobile devices and another design will show in desktop*" - sounds like an XY problem then - this should be done with css `@media`

Comment: Just the design is different classes will be same and functions will be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    $('.btn' + i).addClass( "act-btn" + i);
  }
});

$('.remove').click(function() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    $('.btn' + i).removeClass( "act-btn" + i);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="add">Add class</button> 
<button class="remove">remove class</button>
```

Comment: throwing error "addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: I had changed script

Comment: it worked after replacing `$('.btn-' + i).addClass( "act-btn" + i);` with `$('.btn' + i).addClass( "act-btn" + i);`

Comment: Please make this change in both classes so i can approve the answer.

Comment: Thankyou very much